# Build is failing for Syntax Error - Micromatch

Tags: npm, build, gruntjs, package.json

I'm facing some difficulties while trying to solve the issue below, which is causing my build to fail.

The grunt_default task is failing, and it's complaining about a syntax error in micromatch, I assume this a version conflict related, but I couldn't find a solution for that :

```
12:49:40  > Task :service:grunt_default FAILED
12:49:40  ..main/resources/static/node_modules/liftup/node_modules/micromatch/index.js:44
12:49:40      let isMatch = picomatch(String(patterns[i]), { ...options, onResult }, true);
12:49:40                                                     ^^^
12:49:40  
12:49:40  SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
12:49:40      at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
12:49:40      at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
12:49:40      at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
12:49:40      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
12:49:40      at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
12:49:40      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
12:49:40      at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
12:49:40      at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
12:49:40      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
12:49:40      at Object.<anonymous> (..main/resources/static/node_modules/liftup/node_modules/findup-sync/index.js:12:10)
```

List of dependencies micromatch:

```
ubuntu12#: npm list micromatch
    
    `-- karma@1.7.1
      `-- chokidar@1.7.0
        +-- anymatch@1.3.2
        | `-- micromatch@2.3.11 
        `-- readdirp@2.2.1
          `-- micromatch@3.1.10
```

This is my package.json :

```
"devDependencies": {
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~3.0.4",
    "grunt-cdnify": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~2.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "~1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~2.2.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~2.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~3.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "~2.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-newer": "~1.3.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "~3.0.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~4.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "~3.1.1",
    "grunt-port-pick": "^1.5.3",
    "grunt-wiredep": "~3.0.1",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~1.0.4",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.5.2",
    "time-grunt": "~1.4.0",
    "grunt-jscs": "^3.0.1",
    "grunt-sonar-runner": "^2.4.8",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.12.4",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "~1.1.0",
    "bower": "^1.8.4",
    "highcharts-3d": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.12.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
```

Are you familiar with this issue by any chance?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this already?

Comment: Anyone get to the bottom of this, I tried npm 8, that stopped the build from failing, but there were a lot of new warnings which made me feel this wasn't tthe way forward

Answer (score 11):

Since I have to use Node v6.14.4 and can't update to Node 8 to solve this, I was able to skirt the issue by keeping my `grunt-cli` version at v1.3.1:

```sh
npm install -g grunt-cli@1.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this: [Unexpected token ...](https://github.com/alfredosalzillo/rollup-plugin-multi-input/issues/12)

Apparently it's related to the node version. It needs to be bigger than 8.

Comment: Thanks,
I tried, and it didn't solve my problem.